# WPF application file association: DefaultIcon is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop-application, file-association

I want to association ".abc" file to my WPF application.

I add the association using this code:

```
public class FileAssociation
{
    static RegistryKey Root
    {
        get
        {
            return Registry.CurrentUser;
        }
    }

    // Associate file extension with progID, description, icon and application
    public static void Associate(string extension,
           string progID, string description, string application)
    {
        Require.NotNullOrEmpty(extension, "extension");
        Require.NotNullOrEmpty(progID, "progID");
        Require.NotNullOrEmpty(application, "application");
        Require.NotNullOrEmpty(description, "description");

        Root.CreateSubKey(extension).SetValue("", progID);

        using (var key = Root.CreateSubKey(progID))
        {
            key.SetValue("", description);

            key.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon").SetValue("", ToShortPathName(application).Quote() + ",0");
            key.CreateSubKey(@"Shell\Open\Command").SetValue("", ToShortPathName(application).Quote() + " \"%1\"");

            // Tell explorer the file association has been changed
            SHChangeNotify(0x08000000, 0x0000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }

    // Return true if extension already associated in registry
    public static bool IsAssociated(string extension)
    {
        return (Root.OpenSubKey(extension, false) != null);
    }

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern void SHChangeNotify(uint wEventId, uint uFlags, IntPtr dwItem1, IntPtr dwItem2);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetShortPathName(string lpszLongPath,
        [Out] StringBuilder lpszShortPath, uint cchBuffer);

    // Return short path format of a file name
    private static string ToShortPathName(string longName)
    {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(1000);
        uint iSize = (uint)s.Capacity;
        uint iRet = GetShortPathName(longName, s, iSize);
        return s.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Note:** The Quote() extension method is used just to make string abc to "abc".

Now the file association works fine! I can double click the ".abc" files to open my WPF app.

**But the DefaultIcon is not working**. The DefaultIcon Registery key is set to `"D:\path\to\MyWPFApp.exe",0`. The application icon of my WPF app is set to an icon in the properties page (I can see that the icon of MyWPFApp.exe is already changed). What's wrong? Thanks!

**BTW:** I'm using .NET 4 in Windows 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `DefaultIcon` entry. The first icon is used by default. 
 
remove it and it should work ^^

If I remove the `ToShortPathName` (long name is ok with quotes) and 
change the `Root` property `returns Registry.ClassesRoot` the code works here.

Comment: Thanks. I found the answer later, but forgot to update it here. You're right, the problem is the return value of the Root property. In my case, it should be HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Classes, not HKEY_CURRENT_USER :p